# Set a limit on document size for a mongodb collection

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I want to set a limit on document size for a collection, e.g. documents in the collection are not allowed to exceed 1MB. The number is arbitrary, user defined (more precisely "admin" defined). I don't want to insert the document and then look at its size (not sure if it's even possible). I would like some Error to be raised when someone tries to insert bigger document than allowed. Is there a way to do it via mongodb driver for ruby somehow?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Capped Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-collection-tasks/#capped-collection)?

Comment: @DiodonHystrix Capped collection actually won't help. Yes, you can set maximum size for it, but It won't stop anyone from inserting document which is bigger than I'd need.

Comment: Judging [by this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860739/determining-size-requirements-before-insert-into-mongodb-from-reactive-mongo) you can not check doc's size before it's inserted.

Comment: @DiodonHystrix Just as I feared, I will have to estimate it somehow. Thanks.